# swiftmailer works in dev, error in prod

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using swiftmailer to send my mails on my web app. It works perfectly fine on dev, but when I try in prod, I get this message :

```
Swift_TransportException: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "[mymail]@gmail.com" using 1 possible authenticators
```

Any idea why ? I tried to cache:clear , checked mail and PW

Answer (score 0):

Did you set all parameters like below in app/config/parameters.yml?

```
mailer_transport: 
mailer_encryption: 
mailer_auth_mode: 
mailer_host: 
mailer_user: 
mailer_password:
```

I use gmail and i had to set the parameters like this:

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode: login
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: *****@gmail.com
mailer_password: ******
```